# background uiview still touchable after opening a subview

Tags: ios, swift

I realized when opening a new UIVewcontroller from a parent UIViewcontroller and touching the empty space on my ChildViewContorller (no GUI element control) it calls the Parents touchesBegan:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
```

of my parents view (not visible on the screen).

What wrong or how to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this in my app in this way
1. First define an enum that represents the current view controller

```
enum ViewControllerState {
    case FirstViewController
    case SecondViewController
    // ....
}
```

2. Then define a protocol that define this rule for those view controllers that needs this behavior

```
protocol ViewControllerStatePresentation {
    var viewControllerState: ViewControllerState
}
```

3. Next, make all view controllers(those view controllers that needs this behavior) confirm to this protocol.

```
class ViewController: ViewControllerStatePresentation {
    var viewControllerState: ViewControllerState! 
}
```

4. Now, when you present the child view controller then change the viewControllerState. When the viewControllerState is childViewController make the childViewController's parent's view `userInteractionEnabled` property set to false and set it to true otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. But I am not sure if this is best practice. I would like to handling this with own code as less as possible. It can't imagine that we as coders have to handle this ? Can anyone confirm, that this is best practise. Or do I simply doing something wrong, what I assume ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for me. I am still not sure if it is best practice, but this is for me the most maintainable way to do.

I just added the following to me uiviewcontroller:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
}
```

when touching in empty space it just does nothing.